# Create and use an AppDomain

Tags: .net, appdomain, asp.net-core

So creating AppDomains can always be tricking when the newly created app domain cannot load the assemblies it needs. But with an ASP.NET Core project it seems even harder since the code is compiled into memory (and not Gac'd).  Which means the typical way of resolving and loading based on the file location is not going to work.

If I create a default ASP.NET Core website and add the code below into the controller's ctor it fails on the AssemblyResolve.

```
public MyController(){
    var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");
    appDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => {return null;}
}
```

I wasn't sure if there is a way to inject some sort of context/provider that contained a list of MetadataEmbeddedReferences that ASP had already created, then I could just load that raw assembly into my new appDomain.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't create app domains on core clr so we're pretty much recommending against them. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for responding David.  We are creating a multi tenant website in Azure, which includes a simple rules engine.  For our prototype we generate simple scripts using Roslyn, but we were hoping to load the assemblies in different app domains per tenant.  Our reason being that we didn't want one tenants rules to be able to access another's.  Also I'm not currently using collectable assemblies, so this also gives us a way of cleaning up memory if we feel it's growing faster then IIS would restart app domains.

Comment: @dfowler, Thanks for the new warning in intellisense when you try to use AppDomains with core clr in VS 2015!

Comment: I like the intellisense hint, but since mono supports AppDomains, I wish core clr did too, and then I wish I could load assemblies into them. (just teasing)

Comment: There's actually a much cooler feature in CoreCLR called AssemblyLoadContext. It's the ability to load assemblies into their own "space" without the overhead of an app domain. You don't have to worry about marshaling or serialization.

Comment: @dfowler This looks like what I wanted! I dig around some. Do you have any samples, tests, or Git locations you can point me too?  Looking at your commits it appears the accessor gets setup in the bootstrapper, but I'm not 100% sure how to get the context so I can call LoadStream.  Thanks again!

Comment: For something super basic, look at https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Runtime.CustomLoader. This affects the default load context, which you may not want to do. But you can get the IAssemblyLoadContextFactory as well.